# Código Batch para quitar espacios en blanco

Tags: batch

```
@ECHO OFF

set variable1=    Con espacios    
set variable2= quito los espacios  

echo Variable 1 = [%variable1%]
echo Variable 2 = [%variable2%]
echo.

REM ======= Para quitar espacios en blanco de la variable =======
set variable1=%variable1: =%
set variable2=%variable2: =%

echo Variables sin los espacios en blanco
echo ====================================
echo.
echo Variable 1 = [%variable1%]
echo Variable 2 = [%variable2%]
pause
```

He encontrado este código `batch` que según dice quita los espacios en blanco, pero a mí me da error, ¿me podéis comentar el error del siguiente código? Por favor, si podéis, ponedme un ejemplo con letras de modo que funcione.

Comment: ¿Te fue útil la respuesta? De ser así, acéptala para colaborar con la salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas).

Answer (score 1):

Solo te hace falta agregar `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`:

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set variable1=    Con espacios    
set variable2= quito los espacios  

echo Variable 1 = [%variable1%]
echo Variable 2 = [%variable2%]
echo.

REM ======= Para quitar espacios en blanco de la variable =======
set variable1=%variable1: =%
set variable2=%variable2: =%

echo Variables sin los espacios en blanco
echo ====================================
echo.
echo Variable 1 = [%variable1%]
echo Variable 2 = [%variable2%]
pause
```